# Does Paint add an IP address onto pictures?

Tags: spyware

Does Paint put an IP address (or something else) into a .jpg file?

OS: Windows 8.1

Comment: AFAIK, MS Paint does not... but MS Image Composite Editor, though an *excellent* free tool for JPEG stitching, *does* assign an individual ID used to identify you (or at least your machine) on the net.

Answer (score 1):

The entire bitmap file specification is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

[image]

Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BMPfileFormat.png

As you can see, there isn't really anywhere to store personally identifiable information.

As @DrMoishe Pippik notes, there are free Microsoft graphics tools that do assign an individual ID and include it in output, but Paint does not seem to, provided you save the file as a bitmap.

Comment: The OP is referencing the jpg file format, which permits comments and exiv data.  In that case there are plenty of places to add an identifier.  However unlikely.

Comment: @Paul--I swear I'm turning senile in my old age. Thanks for catching me on that.